# Binary Search Tree Performance fail on large trees

Tags: java

I've been searching for a similar situation but I cannot seem to find one.

Here is what I need to do:

> Write a function that checks if a given binary search tree contains a given value.
>
> For example, for the following tree:
>
> - n1 (Value: 1, Left: null, Right: null)
> - n2 (Value: 2, Left: n1, Right: n3)
> - n3 (Value: 3, Left: null, Right: null)
>
> Call to contains(n2, 3) should return true since a tree with root at n2 contains number 3.

and here's my code:

```
class Node {
 public int value;
 public Node left, right;

 public Node(int value, Node left, Node right) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
 }
}

public class BinarySearchTree {
 public static boolean contains(Node root, int value) {
    if(value == root.value)
        return true;

    if(root.left != null && contains(root.left, value))
        return true;

    if(root.right != null && contains(root.right, value))
        return true;

    return false;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node n1 = new Node(1, null, null);
    Node n3 = new Node(3, null, null);
    Node n2 = new Node(2, n1, n3);

    System.out.println(contains(n2, 3));
 }
}
```

However, it keeps on failing on the last test which is :

> **Performance test on a large tree: Time limit exceeded**

Please If anyone has an idea how I can optimize my process, it will be a big help. I'm actually running out of idea :(

Comment: You don't need to search both the left and right trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance gain of using a binary search tree comes from dividing the values in either bigger or smaller. Hence you need to check if the value is smaller than what currently is in your node and if it is, you look in the left part of the tree, otherwise you look right all until you find the searched value.

Take a look at an Array with many elements (let's say 100). When you search for the 70th value, you will have to make 70 checks `if(foundValue == searchedValue)`.

Now take the same with the tree. Your starting Node holds the value 50, 75 is bigger, so you look at the subset 51-100 in your tree. Here the first Node you encounter is 75, so you look at the subset 51-74 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't use this tree as a binary *search* tree. You check both left and right branches.

A binary search tree ["additionally satisfies the binary search property, which states that the key in each node must be greater than or equal to any key stored in the left sub-tree, and less than or equal to any key stored in the right sub-tree."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Definition)

This means you only need to check one of the branches.

If you check both then a specially constructed test case can make your search to take really long. You'll basically traverse the whole tree.

Comment: Please link to the source of "additionally satisfies...".

Comment: @AndyTurner Done.

Answer (score 0):

I want to give credit to [lexicore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303810/lexicore) and to [ivo-vidovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8596064/ivo-vidovic) for giving me a much more practical explanation on Binary Search Tree. I would've upvote both your post if I have enough reputation. Thank you very much.

on a side note, here is what I did as oppose to my problem with Performance test issue:

```
    if(value <= root.value) {
        if (root.left != null && contains(root.left, value))
            return true;
    } else if (value >= root.value) {
        if (root.right != null && contains(root.right, value))
            return true;
    }
```